# Making Temporary org buffer

Tags: buffers

The following help function prints a message in a temporary buffer.  How can I set the mode of the temporary buffer to `org-mode`.

```
(defun help-show (bfname msg)
  "Makes temporary buffer BFNAME and prints message MSG."

  (when (stringp msg)
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer bfname
    
      (princ msg))

    (pop-to-buffer bfname)))
```

Comment: You do `(with-current-buffer bfname (org-mode))`.

Comment: But I do not have `with-current-buffer`.  I have `pop-to-buffer`.

Comment: The point is that you have to select the buffer as the current buffer in order to change its major mode. Just add the `(with-current-buffer ...)` form before you pop to the buffer.

Comment: How about putting `(org-mode)` after `(pop-to-buffer bfname)`.

Comment: Sure - that should work.

Comment: `with-current-buffer` operates on a buffer but does not switch to it, right?  Is it preferable to set the mode before displaying the buffer or after displaying the buffer?  Could it happen that putting `(org-mode)` after `(pop-to-buffer bfname)` might flicker the buffer whilst changing mode?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, but it does not make much difference here. Theoretically, there could be a flicker of the modeline as the mode changes from `Help` to `Org`, but I think the redisplay is held off until the end of the function so it should not happen. Buit I don't know the details of redisplay, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

With reference to @NickD the solution is to use

```
(with-current-buffer bfname (org-mode))
(pop-to-buffer bfname)
```

Another solution would be

```
(pop-to-buffer bfname) 
(org-mode)
```

Stefan Monnier has pointed out that the first solution is much better, setting the major mode before calling `pop-to-buffer` than the reverse.

This is because `pop-to-buffer` and its friends obey `display-buffer-alist` which can specify different behaviors depending on the buffer's state such as its contents and its major mode.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted answer.